# Receiving empty data on ajax request in spite of available data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get the sub-category list of a category by an AJAX request through `admin-ajax.php`. The categories are under a custom post type. Each category has sub categories. However the AJAX request returns no data in the `console`.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: classipress_params.ajax_url + "?action=dropdown-child-categories",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        cat_id : category_ID
    },
    //show loading just when dropdown changed
    beforeSend: function() {
        ...
    },
    //stop showing loading when the process is complete
    complete: function() {
        .....
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        ....
    },
    // if data is retrieved, store it in html
    success: function( data ) {
        // child categories found so build and display them
        if ( data.success === true ) {
            console.log(data);

            ....
        }
    }
});
```

Am i doing any wrong? `category_ID` is okay, I tested that. The result I get in the console:

```
{
    success: true, 
    html: ""
}
```

Comment: This would depend entirely on your server side code and the value of `category_ID`, which you haven't shown, so we can't help you.

Comment: where is your php code that will respond to your ajax request?

Comment: can you copy you "?action=dropdown-child-categories" page ? what are you doing in it?

Comment: It is possible that the ajax request is returning empty result . Until you post your `php` part it is not possible to say if there is any mistake.

Comment: The ajax request is going to this url : http://www.sayulitalife.com/exchange/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=dropdown-child-categories

Comment: I think you all are making the same point as @RoryMcCrossan :P

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar  
The ajax request is going to this url : http://www.sayulitalife.com/exchange/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=dropdown-child-categories

Comment: @jameshwartlopez The ajax request is going to this url : http://www.sayulitalife.com/exchange/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=dropdown-child-categories

Comment: @MusaMuaz you are legend :D

Comment: I know that , i need what you doing with cat_id , and echo or return which item.., we need source code

Comment: @MusaMuaz : from where will you get the success data ??? from a  function in your functions.php file..right ? (if you are using wordpress)  everybody want that php function code to be pasted here.

Comment: Hello here is the full code of response : http://pastebin.com/t8JV1dkV

Answer (score 0):

Try this changing you action hook name :

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_cp_addnew_dropdown_child_categories', 'cp_addnew_dropdown_child_categories' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_cp_addnew_dropdown_child_categories', 'cp_addnew_dropdown_child_categories' );
```